# Generate moc file for objects declared in hpp and cpp as well

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Is it possible that moc gathers classes with Q_OBJECT macro both from a header and corresponding cpp file and merges the results?

For example, in MyWidget.hpp:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
//...
//signals and slots...
};
```

and in MyWidget.cpp:

```
class AuxLabel : public QLabel
{
Q_OBJECT
//....
//signals and slots
};

#include MyWidget.moc
```

Currently I get a strange error at run time, something similar to:
`symbol lookup error: /....so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN4AuxLabelE`

Comment: How do you call moc? What's your IDE?

Comment: Through the qt module of WAF build system. 

https://waf.io/apidocs/tools/qt5.html#module-waflib.Tools.qt5